# Pandas : in case of duplicate values, remove the row with a particular value in another column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset :

```
id    url     keep_anyway  field
1     A.com   Yes          X
2     A.com   Yes          Y
3     B.com   No           Y
4     B.com   No           X
5     C.com   No           X
```

I want to **remove "url" duplicates with conditions** :

1. Keep duplicates if "keep_anyway" = "Yes".
2. For duplicates with "keep_anyway" = "No", I want to keep the row with "X" value in "field" column.

Expected output is :

```
id    url     keep_anyway  field
1     A.com   Yes          X
2     A.com   Yes          Y
4     B.com   No           X
5     C.com   No           X
```

I have been able to manage condition 1 with :

```
df.loc[(df['keep_aanyway'] =='Yes') | ~df['url'].duplicated()]
```

But how to set up Condition 2 ?

Note that possible values of "field" column are either X or Y, and if I have duplicates, I know FOR SURE that I have one "X" and one "Y" value.

I thought maybe I could sort from A to Z in "field" column then have "keep_first"=True in df.duplicated, but I think it is deprecated, isn't it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
import numpy as np

duplicates = df.duplicated(subset='url')
keep_anyway_bool = df['keep_away'] == 'Yes' # (credit @acushner for pointing this out)
field_bool = df['field'] == 'X'  # (credit @acushner for pointing this out)

df[np.invert(duplicates) | keep_anyway_bool | field_bool]
```

Comment: do you need the `np.where` there? can't you just do `field_bool = df.field == 'X'`?

Comment: Yes, I was initially trying to get everything in the same line, hence the `np.where`. I was going to nest them, then realized that the conditions need to be 'or'ed together...

Comment: NameError: name 'np' is not defined , why is that ?

Comment: `import numpy as np` should cure that. Just use `~duplicates` instead...